# What are library and include directory variables for .so files?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a basic question about opencv. I am using conda environment and installed opencv 3 using conda command. I can see cv2.so in /anaconda2/envs/MyPy2.7TF/lib/python2.7/site-packages. Now, I am trying to use the pyFaceTracker from https://bitbucket.org/amitibo/pyfacetracker . There is a file called setup.py that requires me to modify 'OPENCV_BASE', 'OPENCV_LIB_DIRS', 'OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIRS' etc. I can see only the .so file. What value should I give to these variables?

Comment: You shouldn't need to modify anything in `setup.py`. You should only have to do `python setup.py` per the [docs](https://bitbucket.org/amitibo/pyfacetracker)

Comment: The doc says "You will first need to update setup.py to point to the installation of OpenCV (i.e. set OPENCV_BASE, OPENCV_LIB_DIRS and OPENCV_VERSION global variables to their correct values)."

Answer (score 1):

You can get the path of 'OPENCV_BASE', 'OPENCV_LIB_DIRS', 'OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIRS' from the python shell.
Just activate the conda environment, launch python shell and just use the below code:

```
import cv2
print(cv2.getBuildInformation())
```

This code will print out the installation details of opencv and here you can get the path to this required variables.

Comment: Thanks for this function. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the install path of `opencv` in anaconda, you can use the `CONDA_PREFIX` environment var:

```py
import os

conda_dir = os.environ.get("CONDA_PREFIX")
# Build your path
opencv_install = os.path.join(conda_dir, 'lib', 'python2.7', 'site-packages', 'cv2')
```

I'm not totally sure what lib_dirs are, but you can get the version for any package by using the `__version__` attribute:

```py
import cv2

cv2.__version__
# '4.0.0'
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for taking time to respond to my question. However, I do not have a folder as given by 'opencv_install' ('/home/vandana/anaconda2/envs/MyPy2.7TF/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2'). I just have till 'site_packages', after which I have a cv2.so file. So, my question is - with just this .so static library file, how should I provide path names as required by the setup.py ?

Comment: Does this require a different installation of `opencv`? reading their docs, it looks like you may need to install opencv using something like `apt` on Ubuntu or `brew` on mac which this library points to

Comment: First I want to try using my existing anaconda-opencv without doing any other opencv installation. I guess am a bit lazy there :P

Comment: I tried using a `brew install opencv` and it has what could be assumed to be endless dependencies, so I don't blame you there

Comment: @VandanaRajan I will definitely say that any library that requires you edit `setup.py` is of dubious quality, at least from a best practices standpoint for using/extending code

Comment: Yeah. I see your point. Most researchers focus on flawless implementation of their algorithm and might not care much about the software being user friendly. Anyways, thanks for the help.